# What is the difference between DropDownList.ClearSelection() and DropDownList.SelectedIndex=-1

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the difference between

```
DropDownList.ClearSelection();
```

and

```
DropDownList.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

while working with a dropdownlist?

Edit : 
I am aware of the definitions for these available at  MSDN. Can someone provide differences in implementation/practical use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking into [the source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/UI/WebControls/ListControl.cs) for `System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl`, from which `DropdownList` is derived, it seems like setting `SelectedIndex` actually calls `ClearSelection()`; and if not -1, it will proceed to select the item.

```
    public virtual void ClearSelection() {
        for (int i=0; i < Items.Count; i++)
            Items[i].Selected = false;
    }

    public virtual int SelectedIndex {
        set {
            ...
            if ((Items.Count != 0 && value < Items.Count) || value == -1) {
                ClearSelection();
                if (value >= 0) {
                    Items[value].Selected = true;
                }
            }
            ...
        }
```

Edit: so in answer to your question, calling `ClearSelection()` directly would save you from a couple of (inconsequential) if statements..

Comment: that's the advantage devs got after opensource of code (Y)

Comment: To be fair, I did use reflector cause I'm lazy. But here's the [reference source from Microsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/UI/WebControls/ListControl.cs).

Comment: which reflector you are using?